# Why can the Intel C++ compiler not benefit from this template, while GNU can?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, metaprogramming, intel

In our three dimensional CFD code, performance is crucial. In order to avoid all the calculations in the third dimension in case of a two dimensional simulation, I am experimenting with templates, to avoid double code. With the GCC compiler, this works perfectly, but in case of the Intel compiler this results in a massive performance loss.

The call to my templated function looks like:

```
if(jtot == 1) // If jtot equals 1, then the grid is 2-dimensional
  advecu<2>(ut,u,v,w,dzi4);
else
  advecu<3>(ut,u,v,w,dzi4);
```

My templated function looks like this:

```
template<int dim>
void Advec4::advecu(double * restrict ut, double * restrict u, double * restrict v, double * restrict w, double * restrict dzi4)
{
  // Here comes the initialization of the constants...
  // Loop
  for(int k=grid->kstart; k<grid->kend; k++)
    for(int j=grid->jstart; j<grid->jend; j++)
#pragma ivdep
      for(int i=grid->istart; i<grid->iend; i++)
      {
        ijk = i + j*jj1 + k*kk1;
        ut[ijk] -= ( cg0*((ci0*u[ijk-ii3] + ci1*u[ijk-ii2] + ci2*u[ijk-ii1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]) * (ci0*u[ijk-ii3] + ci1*u[ijk-ii2] + ci2*u[ijk-ii1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]))
                   + cg1*((ci0*u[ijk-ii2] + ci1*u[ijk-ii1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+ii1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-ii2] + ci1*u[ijk-ii1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+ii1]))
                   + cg2*((ci0*u[ijk-ii1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+ii1] + ci3*u[ijk+ii2]) * (ci0*u[ijk-ii1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+ii1] + ci3*u[ijk+ii2]))
                   + cg3*((ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+ii1] + ci2*u[ijk+ii2] + ci3*u[ijk+ii3]) * (ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+ii1] + ci2*u[ijk+ii2] + ci3*u[ijk+ii3])) ) * cgi*dxi;

        if(dim == 3)
        {
          ut[ijk] -= ( cg0*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2-jj1] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1-jj1] + ci2*v[ijk-jj1] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1-jj1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-jj3] + ci1*u[ijk-jj2] + ci2*u[ijk-jj1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]))
                     + cg1*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2    ] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1    ] + ci2*v[ijk    ] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1    ]) * (ci0*u[ijk-jj2] + ci1*u[ijk-jj1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+jj1]))
                     + cg2*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2+jj1] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1+jj1] + ci2*v[ijk+jj1] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1+jj1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-jj1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+jj1] + ci3*u[ijk+jj2]))
                     + cg3*((ci0*v[ijk-ii2+jj2] + ci1*v[ijk-ii1+jj2] + ci2*v[ijk+jj2] + ci3*v[ijk+ii1+jj2]) * (ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+jj1] + ci2*u[ijk+jj2] + ci3*u[ijk+jj3])) ) * cgi*dyi;
        }

        ut[ijk] -= ( cg0*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2-kk1] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1-kk1] + ci2*w[ijk-kk1] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1-kk1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-kk3] + ci1*u[ijk-kk2] + ci2*u[ijk-kk1] + ci3*u[ijk    ]))
                   + cg1*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2    ] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1    ] + ci2*w[ijk    ] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1    ]) * (ci0*u[ijk-kk2] + ci1*u[ijk-kk1] + ci2*u[ijk    ] + ci3*u[ijk+kk1]))
                   + cg2*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2+kk1] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1+kk1] + ci2*w[ijk+kk1] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1+kk1]) * (ci0*u[ijk-kk1] + ci1*u[ijk    ] + ci2*u[ijk+kk1] + ci3*u[ijk+kk2]))
                   + cg3*((ci0*w[ijk-ii2+kk2] + ci1*w[ijk-ii1+kk2] + ci2*w[ijk+kk2] + ci3*w[ijk+ii1+kk2]) * (ci0*u[ijk    ] + ci1*u[ijk+kk1] + ci2*u[ijk+kk2] + ci3*u[ijk+kk3])) )
                   * dzi4[k];
      }
}
```

Why does the Intel compiler mess this up? It seems that it does not process the template before it starts optimizing, which results in a remaining if statement in an inner loop or a loss of performance for whatever other reason.

Comment: What options and what version for each compiler ? How do you measure performance, and how dp you compare results ?

Comment: Hmmm.. I hope this is not the real production code, just some typo error for question. Cause this is quite disturbing. `if(jtot = 1) // If jtot equals 1,`.

Comment: So, what I compare is the performance of 2d and 3d cases in my old code without the template, versus the new templated version. In case the templates don't obstruct the optimization in case of dim == 3, my old code and the new code should be equally fast. This is the case for GCC 4.8 compilers, but not for Intel 13, 14 and 15.

Comment: @luk32 Oops... This is only the code I wrote here, since the real call is much more complex. Thanks though...

Comment: Assuming that you've done all the obvious things like use different optimization levels, you'll probably have to look at the assembly to figure it out.

Comment: @kec I agree, but I was just wondering if there is a particular reason why this does not work. It seems to me an easy task for the compiler.

Comment: I agree that it seems easy for the compiler. But checking the assembly for the if-statement is something that is quick and easy, and thus you don't need to speculate without information. For example, maybe the compiler *did* actually optimize it out, but somehow it's earlier presence is causing some poor behavior in the later compiler optimization phases.